# Find index by value

Tags: php, json, getjson

Good evening all.

Firstly, i apologize for the sheer length of the question. I wanted to be thorough and ensure all information was present along with my intent.

I'm currently looking to develop a simple web-based method of collecting stats from one of my desktop applications. The main purpose of this is for troubleshooting and providing more relevant fixes and feature additions via updates to the end users.

**Details**

- I'll be using PHP 5.2.12, and making use of `$_GET` to grab parameters from the URL and assign them to variables.
- These variables will then be `json_encode` and written to a file (known as "statsfile" or "stats file").
- One of the parameters/variables will be a GUID of some sort. This GUID will be generated by my application based upon a one-way hash created from hardware ID's (though in the code sample, this isn't yet represented).

**The Issue**

The issue i face relates to finding a specific GUID inside my JSON stats file.

Here's what i want to do;

- 1) Locate the submitted GUID inside the statsfile
- 2a) If it doesn't exist, add a new index to the array and populate the data inside
- 2b) If it does exist, overwrite the existing data within the array with the submitted data

It's important that at the end, i'm left with a valid JSON stats file. It's also important that the script is relatively secure.

**Layout and Code**

The layout of my JSON is as follows;

```
[
    {
        "guid": "spritchard",
        "api": "apichoice",
        "build": "2200",
        "temp1": "1",
        "temp2": "2",
        "temp3": "3"
    },
    {
        "guid": "helloworld",
        "api": "someapi",
        "build": "3500",
        "temp1": "4",
        "temp2": "5",
        "temp3": "6"
    }
]
```

The PHP code i'm using is as follows;

```
<?php
$apikey=$_GET["apikey"];
if ($apikey=="apikey8634215")
  {
    $gpuapi=$_GET["api"];
    $buildno=$_GET["build"];
    $temp1=$_GET["temp1"];
    $temp2=$_GET["temp2"];
    $temp3=$_GET["temp3"];
    $guid=$_GET["guid"];

    $statsfile = "./api/application/StatsFile.json"; // Assign the stats file
    $fh = fopen($statsfile, 'a') // 'a' for append, 'w' for write
          or die("Stats File Unavailable");
    $sdata = array('guid' => $guid, 'api' => $gpuapi, 'build' => $buildno, 'temp1' => $temp1, 'temp2' => $temp2, 'temp3' => $temp3);
    fwrite($fh, json_encode($sdata));
    fclose($fh);
    echo json_encode($sdata);

    // reopen stats file to encode data as it should be
//    $cdata = fopen($statsfile, 'r') or die("Stats File Unavailable");
//    $encodedata = fread($cdata, filesize($statsfile));
//    $decodedata = json_decode($encodedata);
//    fclose($cdata);
//    $fh = fopen($statsfile, 'w') or die("Stats File Unavailable");
//    fwrite($fh, json_encode($encodedata));
//    fclose($fh);
  }
else
  {
    die("No Such Usage");
  }
?>
```

You can see i've got `$apikey` used to check if a specific parameter is present. If it's not, then the entire script goes on to die. This is merely a placeholder design at the moment to prevent abuse at a basic level while i develop the system, and i'll investigate more suitable solutions for that in a separate question.

The area that's commented out is the code i attempted to use to rewrite the file with new data and make it valid JSON. I don't know how to go about locating the right GUID in the array, but i'm also struggling to figure out how i'd rewrite the data so it's correctly encoded to JSON. The end result by uncommenting that code is a lot of slashes in the JSON, and the JSON itself isn't valid. Moreover, i'm not confident that the code i've showed here is safe. By all means, i could use a `POST` method, but at the moment, finding out how to update a particular index based on it's GUID is the problem.

**So, to clarify my question, how would i go about finding a specific GUID from the JSON statsfile, updating the data if it exists, or adding a new array index with the submitted data?**

Comment: Any reason why you're not using a system designed for storing and retrieving - and searching for - information, such as a database? sqlite should be available for most PHP installations.

Comment: I don't have physical or root access to the server as it's hosted on shared web hosting. Additionally, it's much easier for me from the software side of things to parse a file of JSON via a reporting tool rather than deal with databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$apikey=$_GET["apikey"];
if ($apikey=="apikey8634215") {
    $newObject = new stdClass();
    $newObject->guid = $_GET["guid"];
    $newObject->api = $_GET["api"];
    $newObject->build = $_GET["build"];
    $newObject->temp1 = $_GET["temp1"];
    $newObject->temp2 = $_GET["temp2"];
    $newObject->temp3 = $_GET["temp3"];
    $statsFile = "./api/application/StatsFile.json";
    $stats = file_exists($statsFile)
        ? json_decode(file_get_contents($statsFile))
        : array()
    ;
    $found = false;
    foreach ($stats as $key => $statItem) {
        if ($statItem->guid == $newObject->guid) {
            $stats[$key] = $newObject;
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        $stats[] = $newObject;
    }
    if (file_put_contents($statsFile, json_encode($stats)) === false) {
        die("Could not save stats");
    }
} else {
    die("No Such Usage");
}
```

This code lacks get parameter existence checks, you should validate the input somehow.